# How to set mouse cursor as hand when it is over a movie clip?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

As question title says, I need to know how to set the mouse cursor to be a hand when it is over a mouse clip. I'm using Flash with Action Script 3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
myClip.buttonMode = true;
```

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Sprite.html#buttonMode

Comment: I had to add `movie_clip.mouseChildren = false;` in order to make it to work besides adding the `buttonMode = true`.

Answer (score 1):

It is a following code.

```
sprite.useHandCursor = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
mc.buttonMode = true;
mc.useHandCursor = true;
mc.tabEnabled = false;
```

If you skip last line your mc will be selectable with Tab button and will have ugly yellow border

Comment: @llya Denisov, the "ugly yellow border" is an important accessibility feature for keyboard-only users, and should not be disabled unless you absolutely know what you are doing.

Comment: Possibly you're right. I only develop games with ActionScipt and those game is not supposed to be used by keyboard-only users. Because of that I didn't take accessibility into consideration :(